# As Part Veela, Why Could Fleur Delacour Use Polyjuice Potion to Transform into Harry, and Why Could Hagrid Not?

Tags: harry-potter, hagrid, polyjuice-potion

It is established in *Deathly Hallows* that Polyjuice Potion is meant for human transformations only:

> ‘Wha’ was tha’ about?’ roared Hagrid.
>   ‘I’m sorry, Harry, but I had to check,’ said Lupin tersely. ‘We’ve been betrayed. Voldemort knew that you were being moved tonight and the only people who could have told him were directly involved in the plan. You might have been an impostor.’
>   ‘So why aren’ you checkin’ me?’ panted Hagrid, still struggling to fit through the door.
>   ‘You’re half-giant,’ said Lupin, looking up at Hagrid. ‘**The Polyjuice Potion is designed for human use only**.’
>   <sub>*Deathly Hallows* - page 63 - Bloomsbury - chapter 5, *The Fallen Warrior*</sub>

And it's established Fleur Delacour is part Veela in *Goblet of Fire*:

> [Ollivander] twirled the wand between his long fingers like a baton and it emitted a number of pink and gold sparks. Then he held it close to his eyes and examined it carefully.
>   ‘Yes,’ he said quietly, ‘nine and a half inches ... inflexible ... rosewood ... and containing ... dear me …’
>   ‘An ’air from ze ’ead of a Veela,’ said Fleur. ‘One of my grandmuzzer’s.’
>   So Fleur *was* part Veela, thought Harry [.]
>   <sub>*Goblet of Fire* - page 270 - Bloomsbury - chapter 18, *The Weighing of the Wands*</sub>

**Why was Fleur able to take Polyjuice Potion and transform into Harry while Hagrid was not? Neither Fleur nor Hagrid are fully human.**

I'm *not* interested in an answer that says it was possible because Fleur had more human blood than Hagrid. It's clear from canon that "human use only" means **human use only**. Can this discrepancy be explained within the spirit of canon? I don't know of a canon explanation for this question, or that J.K. Rowling addresses it in any of her interviews, but if you can find a quote or passage from the books that answers this, I would love it if you left an answer. Please no HP Wiki/Wikia answers.

<sub>I checked for this question under "Fleur" and didn't find it. I hope it's not a dupe.</sub>

Comment: I would guess it's not so much an arbitrary "more human blood than Hagrid" as it is "more human blood than Veela blood".  Hagrid's exactly half/half.  (But, just a guess - hence why it's a comment ;) )

Comment: Good one. I don't think there can be an in-universe answer to this. Veela may be able to look like humans (and beautiful ones at that) but from how they changed appearance at the Quidditch World Cup, they're definitely very different. At least as different as giants or goblins are. Neither are classified as "beasts" according to "Fantastic Beasts & Where To Find Them", but neither are they human. I think this is one of those mistakes JKR says she's made.

Comment: @Izkata - Well, okay, semantics, and I see where you're coming from. My thought, though, is that no matter the percentage, only 100% humans should take Polyjuice. 50% or 75% human isn't enough, if I'm interpreting correctly. This is a tough one! Thanks for commenting :)

Comment: @DavidStratton -- Do you have a link to JKR's quote saying this? According to the guidelines in *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* I think Veelas would be considered beings in Potterverse while giants would be considered beasts, the difference being that a “being” is *any creature that has sufficient intelligence to understand the laws of the magical community and to bear part of the responsibility in shaping those laws.* (Scholastic - page xxi) Technically I think this would include goblins as well.

Comment: I think I  mis-phrased it. Within the last three weeks, I ran across a quote from JKR stating that she's made continuity mistakes (But I can't find the interview now).  I think I phrased it to sound like "JKR has said that this is one of her continuity mistakes", when I meant "JKR has said that she's made continuity mistakes, and that I think this is one of them." I also think giants barely squeak into the "beings" category - they have culture, customs, language, and Hagrid went, assuming giants had sufficient smarts to choose sides. And they're not listed in Fantastic beasts.

Comment: Quote where she admits mistakes is in pureferret's answer here: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18265/how-could-dudley-have-wrecked-his-playstation-if-the-playstation-didnt-exist-ye  although he didn't cite the source either...

Comment: @DavidStratton - That makes sense -- thanks for clarifying :) I'm on the fence about giants; I tend to lean more towards them being beasts because I don't know if they have the capability to bear part of the responsibilities of shaping wizarding laws. I see your point too, though. Thanks for the link to Pureferret's post with the quote. :)

Comment: I agree with @Izkata, because while Fleur could've been at minimum only 1/4 veela, Hagrid was definitely 1/2 giant through his mother. Also, in my opinion veela are more similar to humans than giants.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

First of all, I think you are slightly confused about directions:

- Fleur able to take Polyjuice Potion and transform into Harry as you said
- Whereas, Lupin testing Harry and NOT testing Hagrid meant that **he was not worried that Hagrid was a fake Polyjuiced DE impostor**.

In other words, what Lupin said was that **it is not possible was for a human to transform into a half-giant (or non-human)** [remember what happened to Hermione when she Polyjuiced herself into a cat in CS?] - **but that didn't imply anything about a cross-breed transforming into human as a target**. Thus, Fleur's transform into Harry doesn't necessarily make for a contradiction.

**The limitation might only be on the target as opposed to the drinker of the potion.**

---

Leaving aside that obvious explanation, there are 4 options possible based on interpreting canon even assuming that someone could Polyjuice into Fleur (but not Hagrid):

1. Polyjuice is (unlike Transfiguration) somewhat mass- or volume- dependent. While having different sized humans transform into Harry may be plausible, having a [1000 lb Hagrid who was twice human height](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16885/how-big-is-hagrid) is stretchin the laws of <strike>science</strike> magic - ditto transforming a human into Hagrid.
2. This is most likely due to Hagrid being part-*giant* than the proportions. **Giants in general seem immune to magic** (see the scenes in HBP for example); and therefore it's quite possible that Polyjuice simply doesn't work well on them, same as any other magic.

   One of the reasons stated in canon for Hagrid's magic resistance is general thick-skinness and toughness of giants physically. It's possible that this purely biological physical distinction is problematic for Polyjuice  transformation.

   **Heck, Hagrid's hair may simply refuse to be dissolved in the potion, being too tough.**
3. Another possibility is that Giants - while technically the same species due to there being possible cross-offspring - are too genetically different from humans compared to Veela. Remember what happened to Hermione when she Polyjuiced herself into a cat in CS - that was likely due to genetic conflicts.

Comment: I don't think there's any difference in "non-human" status between Fleur and Hagrid. Bottom line, according to JKR's own writing, Fleur should not have been able to use Polyjuice Potion at all; neither should Hagrid, as noted. It doesn't say "if you're a petite non-human, go ahead and use Polyjuice" or "If you're a massive non-human, don't dare to try Polyjuice." It says Polyjuice is intended for human use **only**. I just find this very puzzling. :)

Comment: @Slytherincess - that's why I started out explaining why the whole premise is different - Lupin's concern (or rather lack of it) was about a HUMAN taking PJ potion to turn into Hagrid; NOT about Hagrid drinking PJ potion. Which is directly corroborated by Hermione's CS experience. E.g. the rule is NOT about non-humans taking the potion; but about humans using the potion to turn into non-humans

Comment: I remembered something -- I asked whether Polyjuice was a form of Transfiguration. I got one answer which concluded Polyjuice included Transfiguration. http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14584/is-polyjuice-potion-a-form-of-transfiguration Polyjuice can include the same issues of the displacement of mass as Transfiguration can. :)

Comment: I just don't interpret Lupin's statement that way. It is clear to me that Lupin is saying non-humans should not take Polyjuice Potion in this context. Are you saying there would be no negative effects on Fleur or Hagrid if they took Polyjuice? :)

Comment: @Slytherincess - there **were** no negative effects on Fleur - she did turn into Harry. As far as Hagrid, I listed 3 reasons why there might **plausibly** be some issues, ranging from the PJ potion not working at all due to his magic resistance, to him looking like a (no pun intended) a giant version of Harry. But that's mostly speculation.

Comment: Also, sorry but you're reading Lupin 100% wrong. See your quote: "*Lupin To Harry*: You might have been an impostor.’  - *Hagrid*: ‘So why aren’ you checkin’ me?’". Hagrid is upset that Lupin didn't verify that HE, Hagrid, was not an impostor - e.g. a DE who looked like Hagrid. THAT was what Lupin was responing to.

Comment: I *know* who Lupin is responding to. The quote I'm interested in is *‘The Polyjuice Potion is designed for human use only.’* I don't believe I'm reading that wrong. The rest of the quote I included was just for context. But to ask -- why were there no negative effects on Fleur? Because, as I mentioned in my original post, she's clearly not 100% human. Is there a canon reason for this, or is it just a discrepancy?

Comment: @Slytherincess DVK has it right here; The idea is that the potion is designed to transform _into_ a human _only_, **not** that _only_ 100% human's can use it. This is supported by canon, we see Hermione fail to turn into a cat, and we see that Lupin doesn't check Hagrid.

Comment: @NominSim or DVK has it wrong and it's just a mistake. It happens.

Comment: "Human use" makes it sound like only humans should use it, not that it should only be used to turn into a human.

Comment: @Rob That interpretation of "human use" is not supported by canon. If "only humans should use it", then Lupin **would have** suspected Hagrid since it could have been a human that used the potion to turn into him. The interpretation that it can **only** turn the user into a human **is** supported by canon however. (Hermione with the cat, and Lupin not being suspicious of Hagrid)

Comment: @NominSim that makes sense now. My brain was stuck in a loop. It has become clear now.

Comment: @NominSim - As I read it, Lupin's comment to Hagrid implies that Hagrid cannot use Polyjuice because he's **not 100% human** -- he's half-giant, and therefore why would Lupin need to interrogate Hagrid, because of *course* a half-giant cannot use Polyjuice to begin with. I do not believe I'm reading canon wrong; I *understand* what you all are saying. I do not expect people on this site to ever agree with my POV. Also, no one has mentioned Fleur and why she *could* take the potion. It absolutely is a contradiction and I expect it to be addressed to truly answer the original question.

Comment: @Slytherincess - but that's the whole point NominSim and me are making - the contradiction does NOT exist because Lupin's comment to Hagrid does not mean what you think it means. It's *inconceivable* but most likely you are simply not reading it correctly (admittedly, based on very poor and sloppy wording by JKR). It's a problem with parsing JKR's English and not with canon consistency.

Comment: @Slytherincess - Lupin sees Hagrid there in front of him, so he isn't talking about whether _Hagrid_ himself could use Polyjuice at all, he is talking about whether **someone else** could use Polyjuice to _turn into_ Hagrid. It doesn't make sense for Lupin to say "Oh I don't have to worry because you can't use Polyjuice", because Hagrid is standing right there, it was either someone else who had turned into Hagrid, or Hagrid himself. Lupin's comment indicates that the potion is for human use only, meaning it couldn't turn someone into Hagrid.

Comment: @Slytherincess I realise this is an old post, but when you say, “As I read it, Lupin's comment to Hagrid implies that Hagrid cannot use Polyjuice because he's not 100% human -- he's half-giant, and therefore why would Lupin need to interrogate Hagrid, because of course a half-giant cannot use Polyjuice to begin with”, **you are unequivocally reading canon wrong**. There is no way the quote can logically mean that, unless Polyjuice does not work _either way_ with not-100%-humans (and we know from Fleur’s transformation that this is not the case). If there were either no limitations or the →

Comment: → only limitation was that non-humans couldn’t _use_ Polyjuice as the ‘source’, then Lupin would have checked Hagrid, because he could still be an impostor (a human transformed into Hagrid). If the limitation were that non-humans could be neither source nor target, then Hagrid would be beyond suspicion, but Fleur wouldn’t have been able to transform either. The **only** possible scenario is thus that the limitation is on the _target_, which must be human. No other scenario fits the facts and Lupin’s statement.

Comment: Another possibility, giants and half-giants are shown to be resistant to certain magics.  Polyjuice might fall into that category.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, am I the only one who reads this whole argument and just thinks...https://xkcd.com/915/?

Answer (score 14):

Assumption: neither Fleur not Hagrid are 100% human.

**If** Polyjuice Potion can only be used by someone who is 100% human, **then**

- Death Eaters could have impersonated either Fleur or Hagrid;
- Neither Fleur nor Hagrid could have impersonated Harry.

This violates canon, because (1) Fleur could impersonate Harry, and (2) there was no risk that Hagrid could secretly be a Death Eater. Therefor this can't be the case.

()

**If** Polyjuice Potion can only be used to turn someone into a human, **then**

1. Neither Fleur nor Hagrid could have secretly been a Death Eater.
2. Either Fleur or Hagrid could have impersonated Harry.

This is rather canon compliant as an explanation and doesn't violate the assumption. In other words, despite the sloppy English, this is the correct interpretation.

Comment: Although this does make me wonder if someone could impersonate Remus Lupin; he's not exactly 100% human either as a werewolf.

Comment: I dunno: I see werewolves as having caught an incurable disease with moon-induced symptoms. It doesn't change what the victim was born as.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility of course is that Prof Lupin was simply mistaken. He was a bright wizard indeed, but not a potions master, and he may not have known every nuance of the Polyjuice Potion's actions. I have no evidence for this other than the fact that Lupin was human and therefore fallible.

Comment: -1 for suggesting that Lupin doesn't know everything. Just kidding ;) But I think that Lupin is very considerate and cautious, so I doubt he wouldn't check Hagrid if he wasn't 100% positive that it was really him.

Answer (score 0):

I think the premise of the argument itself is flawed. Hagrid is a half giant. This is established. Hagrid is the direct offspring here. May be Fleur isn't. Imagine two purebloods siring a pureblood who marries a halfblood/muggle to sire a halfblood/squib. In my opinion her grandmother being Veela does not essentially mean she's part Veela.

Comment: I do not intend to make Harry look stupid here :)

Comment: I gave a canon quote that states Fleur is part Veela. JKR refers to her as "the Veela girl" quite a few times throughout *Goblet of Fire*. If you read through chapter 16 - *The Goblet of Fire* - you can confirm this. I don't think "Maybe she's adopted!" or "Maybe she's just not part Veela", when canon clearly indicates she is, is quite what I'm looking for, although of course you're welcome to theorize whatever you'd like. :)

Comment: Pure/half-bloods, muggles, and squibs are all fully human, the only difference is how much magic they and their ancestors exhibited. Someone with a Veela (i.e. nonhuman) grandmother is only 3/4 human. Period.

Answer (score 0):

Size may also be a factor, Fleur was human sized as well as being 3/4s human. Where as Hagrid was 1/2 human and if you go by the books at least 11ft tall and probably weighed close to a ton

Comment: Is there any evidence to support this, or are you just speculating? Speculation alone doesn't make for a very good answer.

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer is that Fleur is 3/4 human while Hagrid is only 1/2. Plus Hagrid is alot bigger then Harry and Fleur so the magic probably isn't designed to turn somthing that big into somthing so much smaller, hence Hermione and the cat hair. The last reason could be simply that the Wizarding world is not fact and is created by a human being who will make mistakes from time to time meaning Harry Potter shouldn't be read like a non-fiction text book

Comment: Please don’t insult question askers and your final point isn’t also much of an answer. Because it’s fiction, the writer wrote  so or the writer made a mistake are generally considered non answers.

Comment: I wasn't trying to insult anyone, if that was how I came across then I apologise. Also I am new to this website and it feels a bit like you are being a bit judgmental and seem to critisize everything I write. I have only written twice and both times you have edited and critisized what I have written. Can you please stop that? Once again I apologise if i sounded rude before

Comment: Editing is just part of how content is curated on this site, here all I did was remove what is essentially an insult from the start of it. You might want to take the [tour] if you haven’t already because it gives some insight into how this site works as it is different to a typical discussion forum. And for what it’s worth I didn’t criticise or “judge” your question but actually defended it to another user.