# Can squibs brew potions?

Tags: harry-potter

It came to my attention that even though squibs can't cast spells, they can work in a magical environment and they can see magical creatures.

My question is then, considering (so far as we know) that brewing potions doesn't actively involve using magic, **with the right instructions, ingredients, tools and a fire could a squib become a potion master?**

Comment: I can't think of magical skills actually required in potion brewing, although getting at the right ingredients may be a bit tricky for a squib (although I know you say they have all they need)

Comment: Many potions do require the use of a wand. I suspect many of them would require special magical fire as well, or need ingredients which can be recognized only by magical people

Comment: I was thinking that Argus Filch could've have had a much easier life at hogwarts it he'd at least learned to brew potions. For instance we know there are magical mess remover potion. Not Not only could he do his job more quickly more effcienlty, but he wouldn't be as horrible a character towards students as in canon, because his sense of self worth wouldn't be as low or as dependant on catching "these disgusting little culrpits" as in canon.

Comment: @user24308, this doesn't explain why nobody provides him with the potions to use (not your fault, of course; the books', perhaps). Even if he can't brew them himself I'm sure he knows how to pour. Nobody bothers to make his job any easier, nor am I sure why he even does ANY cleaning, what with all the super-eager elves around :)

Comment: Can squibs see magical creatures? I think they can not, at least Miss Figg could not see the Dementors, as implied in Harrys trial.

Comment: There is an earlier question on this site "Can a Muggle become a potions maker?" that has two answers convincingly settling this question in the *negative*. The point is that one will have to use ones wand at some stage in the process (and there must be magic for the wand to channel).

Comment: Nowhere, nowhere in the books do we see a magic wand being used to brew potions, execept perhaps to control the fire.

Comment: "There will be no foolish wand-waving or silly incantations in this class." They use knives,pestle and mortar, etc.. but no wand. Rowling's word may be the word of god as far as HP is concerned, but she really is making this out of the blue!If one must absolutely be a wizard to brew potions then it is a passove effect magic being transferred from the wizard to the potion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a Muggle become a potions maker?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11846/can-a-muggle-become-a-potions-maker)

Comment: @RyanPerry A Squib is not a Muggle!

Comment: Same s**t different pile...both are people who are not magically inclined. You're just splitting hairs.

Answer (score 6):

**No, a squib (or a muggle) cannot brew a potion.**

As revealed in the [latest update on Pottermore](http://simplypotterheads.com/post/105264424687/pottermore-clue-for-12-14-2013-answer-professor), although potion-making doesn't appear to have a great deal of magical input, the reality is that **at some point in the process wandwork is essential** to add magic to the ingredients.

> *"It is often asked whether a Muggle could create a magic potion, given
> a Potions book and the right ingredients. **The answer, unfortunately,
> is no. There is always some element of wandwork necessary to make a
> potion** (merely adding dead flies and asphodel to a pot hanging over a
> fire will give you nothing but nasty-tasting, not to mention
> poisonous, soup)."*

Since a squib is incapable of performing wanded magic, they would also, by definition be incapable of brewing a working magical potion.

This was backed up in an [interview in 2006](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2006/0801-radiocityreading1.html), albeit one largely focused on muggles rather than squibs:

> *Q*: Can muggles brew potions if they follow the exact instructions and they have all of the ingredients?
>
> *JKR*: **Well, I'd have to say no, because there is always...there are magical component in the potion, not just the ingredients. So, at some point they will have to use a wand**. I've been asked what would happen if a Muggle picked up a magic wand in my world, and the answer would probably be something accidental... possibly quite violent. Because wands, in my world, is merely a vehicle, a vessel for what lies inside the person. There is a very close relationship -- as you know -- between the wand that each wizard uses and themselves. In fact, we'll find out more about that in book 7.
>
> For a muggle you need the ability, in other words, to make these things work properly but you're right and I think that's an interesting point. Potions seems, on the face of it, to be the most Muggle-friendly subject. **But there does come a point in which you need do more than stir.**

---

The question still remains whether a squib or a muggle could assemble *previously magicked* potion components and *combine them* into a working potion but the overall impression seems to be no, they could not.