# Can a squib or muggle produce a potion with wizard help?

Tags: harry-potter, wizards, muggles, potions, squib

Could a squib or muggle produce a potion if a wizard did the wandwork for them?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to see how you could improve your question, secondly, take a look at the [tour](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a better idea of how this site works and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Related questions: [Can a Muggle become a potions maker?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/11846/31394) and [Can squibs brew potions?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/53325/31394)