# Can a Muggle use magical objects (potion, Time-Turner, etc)?

Tags: harry-potter, muggles

Say that a wizard were to foolishly give a Muggle a potion, Time-Turner, broomstick, or some other magical object. Would the Muggle be able to use it (or drink it, in the case of a potion)? To be clear, I'm talking about objects made by wizards and given to Muggle, so no [Muggle making potions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/11846/13217).

The closest thing I could find is an almost certainly non-canon *Harry Potter* skit for the 80th birthday of Queen Elizabeth II. In this, Hermione <s>blatantly violates the International Statute of Wizarding Secrecy</s> gives an envelope that contains "a charm that can be worked by Muggle" with the following instructions:

> Dear Prime Minister,
>
> Happy birthday to the Queen from the students of Hogwarts. In view of this special occasion, we send you a charm that can be worked by Muggles, as long as they are in possession of a little borrowed magic, which we include in the envelope.
>
> This is a limited one-time only offer. Stand up straight, point both to the left and the right, and shout the following phrase: “Accio Her Majesty’s handbag”.

Do these sort of magical objects actually exist in the canon *Harry Potter* universe, that can be used by wizards and Muggles alike?

Answer (score 6):

### **Potions, yes.**

Tom Riddle Sr., a Muggle, is presumed to have taken a love potion given to him by Merope Gaunt, and it worked perfectly well on him just as it would have on a wizard.

> ‘Can you not think of any measure Merope could have taken to make Tom Riddle forget his Muggle companion, and fall in love with her instead?’
>
> ‘The Imperius Curse?’ Harry suggested. ‘Or a love potion?’
>
> ‘Very good. Personally, I am inclined to think that she used a love potion. I am sure it would have seemed more romantic to her and I do not think it would have been very difficult, some hot day, when Riddle was riding alone, to persuade him to take a drink of water. In any case, within a few months of the scene we have just witnessed, the village of Little Hangleton enjoyed a tremendous scandal. You can imagine the gossip it caused when the squire’s son ran off with the tramp’s daughter Merope.
>
> <sub>-- *HP and the Half-Blood Prince* ([extract on Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/book-extract-long/love-child))</sub>

While it's not certain that she did use a love potion, we can tell from Dumbledore's supposition that love potions must work on Muggles. If they didn't, Dumbledore would know, and would have immediately excluded a love potion as a possibility.

There's also the Ton-Tongue Toffee which the Weasley twins 'accidentally' gave to Dudley Dursley. I'm not sure whether this necessarily involves *potions* as such - perhaps there could be a charm or jinx embedded in the toffee somehow? - but at any rate, it certainly works on Muggles. (Hat tip to @Valorum for reminding me of this in comments.)

### **Time-Turners, probably.**

I'm not aware of any canon instance of a Muggle using a Time-Turner. However, I'd guess that Time-Turners derive their abilities from magic done on them *during their construction* rather than by the person using them, so their performance shouldn't depend at all on the magical ability (or lack thereof) of the user.

Comment: Ahem; http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Ton-Tongue_Toffee

Comment: I think the matter of *control* is the key issue.  With magical prank objects such as regurgitating toilets, the wizard who casts the spell is in control even though the muggle victim triggers the action.

Comment: There's also a story on Pottermore about one of Harrys ancestors giving potions to the muggles around him to heal them. Cant remember the details now though

Answer (score 0):

They can definitely use Portkeys (even without a wizard or witch there).

> Accidents have occurred, however; two Muggle dog-walkers found themselves accidentally transported to a Celestina Warbeck concert in 2003, because their dogs had run off with an old trainer on Clapham Common.
> *Wizarding World, [Portkey Article](https://www.wizardingworld.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/portkeys)*

I'm not sure broomsticks would — in the flying lesson it's clear that they won't even work for some witches and wizards, so a Muggle who doesn't believe the broomstick will fly probably won't get very far.